# React component functionality

Tags: reactjs

I found a nice draggable svg component here:

https://gist.github.com/hashrock/0e8f10d9a233127c5e33b09ca6883ff4

It's basically a Circle component with the ability to be draggable.

But, I would like to add more elements and not only Circle ( For example I want also Rectangle and a generic SVG that can be inserted )

How could it be done?
I thought about generic HOC lets say "Draggable" and inside should be the `move` functions,
but what would I write on the `render()` part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use render props. Convert the Circle component to a Draggable component and render it like this:

**Draggable.js**

```
return (
  {this.props.render({
      cx:{position.x},
      cy:{position.y},
      onPointerDown:{handlePointerDown},
      onPointerUp:{handlePointerUp},
      onPointerMove:{handlePointerMove},
      active:{position.active}
  })}
);
```

Then you can create Draggables objects with different render functions:

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="400" height="400">
      <Draggable render={renderCircle} />
      <Draggable render={renderRect} />
    </svg>
  );
```

}